# Extracting accurate product color and background color from an image using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to extract the product color and background color from images where a model is wearing the product (e.g., a dress). My current approach involves masking out the skin and hair colors and then using KMeans clustering to find the dominant colors. However, the results aren't always accurate, especially when the product color is similar to the background or the model's skin/hair.

Here's the code I've been using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mask_human_colors(image):
    # Convert the image to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    
    # Define a range for skin colors in HSV
    lower_skin = np.array([0, 20, 70], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_skin = np.array([20, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
    skin_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_skin, upper_skin)
    
    # Define a range for common hair colors in HSV (This is a rough estimate and might need adjustments)
    lower_hair = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_hair = np.array([180, 255, 60], dtype=np.uint8)
    hair_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_hair, upper_hair)
    
    # Combine the skin and hair masks
    human_mask = cv2.bitwise_or(skin_mask, hair_mask)
    
    # Mask the image to remove human colors
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=~human_mask)
    
    return masked_image

def extract_top_colors(image, k=2):
    pixels = image.reshape(-1, 3)
    pixels = pixels[np.any(pixels != [0, 0, 0], axis=1)]  # Removing black pixels
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, n_init=10)
    kmeans.fit(pixels)
    sorted_labels = np.argsort(np.bincount(kmeans.labels_))[::-1]
    colors = [kmeans.cluster_centers_[label].astype(int).tolist() for label in sorted_labels]
    return colors

# Usage:

image_path = '/content/white_dress.JPG'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Mask human colors
masked_image = mask_human_colors(image)

# Extract top colors
dominant_colors = extract_top_colors(masked_image, k=2)

print(f"1st Dominant Color (RGB): {dominant_colors[0]}")
print(f"2nd Dominant Color (RGB): {dominant_colors[1]}")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(20, 5))
ax[0].imshow(image)
ax[0].set_title("Original Image")
ax[1].imshow(masked_image)
ax[1].set_title("Image after Masking Human Colors")
ax[2].imshow([dominant_colors])
ax[2].set_title("Top 2 Dominant Colors")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here's an example image I'm working with: [image]

In some cases, the extracted product color is a lighter shade than the actual product or it picks the background color.

current solution result shows: -

[image]

I'm looking for suggestions to improve the accuracy of color extraction or alternative techniques that might be more effective.

Thank you

Comment: perhaps have them bodypaint the models blue/green from head to toe. that'll be very easy to remove. -- I heard that human skin tones form one or a few easy to separate areas in some color spaces. that might help. -- this will always require some specialcasing of various human features that aren't skin (eyes, teeth). either some human has to erase those in photoshop or you do it with AI/DL. -- you can forget about trying to cluster the garment's colors. they're too variable. -- you can forget about trying to separate the background from the garment if both are white. you need greenscreening.

Comment: In your case, I would think about training an ML model which segments out the dress. The hardest part would be the labeling but overall it might be more time saving than implementing 10000 special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked on color extraction before, I understand that it is very difficult to do specially in images with complex backgrounds. But there are several ways you can improve the accuracy of your color extraction process. Firstly, instead of manually defining skin and hair color ranges, consider using a pre-trained deep learning model for foreground segmentation (models like Mask R-CNN or U-Net).

After segmentation, you can should further refine the mask using thresholding to remove small artifacts and fine-tune the mask. Then, i feel that you should consider analyzing histograms of color channels to identify peaks corresponding to the product's color. You can set thresholds on these peaks to extract the dominant product color. If you have not done this before, you can use a third party tool such as Cloudinary that provides a [histogram of 32 RGB colors](https://cloudinary.com/blog/api_for_extracting_semantic_image_data_colors_faces_exif_data_and_more) that best match your image using a simple api call. If you have access to a semantic segmentation model, it can help you identify different object classes in the image. You can then focus on the region classified as the product. Again, for this purpose, you can use the api I mentioned above or any other tool too.

Lastly, use background subtraction techniques to remove the background entirely. This can simplify the color extraction process. For this, you can use OpenCV's `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` or some other online options.